# How to construct R Tree(STR Method) with rectangle bounding boxes?

Tags: string, r-tree, bounding

How to construct R Tree based on Sort Tile Recursion Method of rectangle bounding boxes along with searching alone?
Totally 12 bounding boxes with (minx, miny) & (maxx , maxy)

I don't need to delete or update any nodes.

Comment: @user71097 : bad luck. Edited to make it more readible, and voted to close as not a real question. Please only ask questions where you actually put some effort in. If you have tried code and it didn't work, give the error and people will help you. If you ask "do my work for me", your question will be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Check the original paper... you use the mean.
In fact this problem arises with point data, too: after a first bulk loading step you may have more pages than fit the root node, so you need to bulk-load another level.

For point data, STR bulk loaded pages will not overlap; at higher levels and for rectangles they will likely do. The popularity of STR probably stems a lot from point data.

P.S. with a total of 12 bounding boxes, using an R-Tree sounds like overkill to me. I'd set the page size clearly larger than 12 entries. And well, when your tree consists of a single node, it isn't really a tree ...